# What should be the better solution for store and manage big data?

Tags: mysql, filesystems, file-storage, bigdata, database

I have a PHP application which request a API in every half hour and get chunk of data. The amount of data approximately 30 million every month.

So this data is flooded database every day. And at the end of the year it cross approximately (30*12) = 360 million data or more.

I just store those data and when user request for a specific data I get from it. So what could be the better solution for this kind of application for store those data and get a specific data? I am now using MYSQL. Is MYSQL able to handle those data as per my request or I store those data in a file system ? Because I cannot change MYSQL at this situation.

Comment: day is 30M year is 360M. Maybe you meant month is 30M

Comment: Never mind. ok thank you

Comment: In my mind this is not big data

Comment: @Drew So what exactly it is ?

Comment: Probably 300 times the volume you have now.

Comment: You need not only sound db design with rollups, but a devops team that can support it. So that is something you need to develop as your data growth does. And take that to your stakeholders. There are people here on the stack in Jobs or freelance that can support your org. Or you develop those skills from within.